# How to know function return type and argument types?

Tags: python, types

While I am aware of the duck-typing concept of Python, I sometimes struggle with the type of arguments of functions, or the type of the return value of the function.

Now, if I wrote the function myself, I DO know the types. But what if somebody wants to use and call my functions, how is he/she expected to know the types? 
I usually put type information in the function's docstring (like: `"...the id argument should be an integer..."` and `"... the function will return a (string, [integer]) tuple."`)

But is looking up the information in the docstring (and putting it there, as a coder) really the way it is supposed to be done?

**Edit:** While the majority of answers seem to direct towards "yes, document!" I feel this is not always very easy for 'complex' types.
 For example: how to describe *concisely* in a docstring that a function returns a list of tuples, with each tuple of the form (node_id, node_name, uptime_minutes) and that the elements are respectively a string, string and integer?
The docstring PEP documentation doesn't give any guidelines on that.
I guess the counterargument will be that in that case classes should be used, but I find python very flexible because it allows passing around these things using lists and tuples, i.e. *without* classes.

Comment: The short answer is "yes".  The long answer is "yes, of course".  I don't know if you've looked at much Python code, but you should probably **update** the question to indicate what packages you actually use so we can direct you to code you can read to see how things are done in the library code you're actually using right now.

Comment: @S.Lott: I am currently struggling with the mechanize package, but I guess it is just (unfortunately) poorly documented.

Comment: Python's cool because you can write lots of code quickly and you don't have to worry about mundane things such as return types, argument types, runtime performance, people who have to use and maintain your spaghetti code for the next 10 years etc.  Sigh.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how dynamic languages work. It is not always a good thing though, especially if the documentation is poor - anyone tried to use a poorly documented python framework? Sometimes you have to revert to reading the source.

Here are some strategies to avoid problems with duck typing:

- create a language for your problem domain
- this will help you to name stuff properly
- use types to represent concepts in your domain language
- name function parameters using the domain language vocabulary

Also, one of the most important points:

- **keep data as local as possible!**

There should only be a few well-defined and documented types being passed around. Anything else should be obvious by looking at the code: Don't have weird parameter types coming from far away that you can't figure out by looking in the vicinity of the code...

Related, (and also related to docstrings), there is a technique in python called `doctests`. Use that to document how your methods are expected to be used - and have nice unit test coverage at the same time!

Comment: Numpy documentation is a good representative example of the philosophy stated in the answer above.

Answer (score 289):

Well things have changed a little bit since 2011! Now there's [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in Python 3.5 which you can use to annotate arguments and return the type of your function. For example this:

```
def greeting(name):
  return 'Hello, {}'.format(name)
```

can now be written as this:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
  return 'Hello, {}'.format(name)
```

As you can now see types, there's some sort of optional static type checking which will help you and your type checker to investigate your code.

for more explanation I suggest to take a look at the blog post on type hints in [PyCharm blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/).

Comment: Note that a type hinting syntax was also suggested for Python 2.7  [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) in the same PEP-0484. And it works in PyCharm, at least from v 2017.3 .

Comment: If the greeting function with exactly same definition returns an object of type of int, no error will raise. So what is usage of this kind of type checking if you mention the return type explicitly, but don't obey the rule and return different type of object ?

Comment: @Arashsyh: Yes, you are right, type hinting does not turn Python into statically typed language, it's up to you to use the right types in the right manner. And those type hints help you - to develop faster, self-document your code or get warning when you mess something up. Especially when you use PyCharm (or similar IDE), it will warn you in case you use different type and helps with few other things. I recommend to read the blog post suggested in the answer above.

Comment: Is this faster computationally?

Comment: Until today, I did not have any problems with datatypes in Python3. But recently I missed a return type in Pandas and had some headache - of course because of my own mistake, not because of Python3. I did not notice this great change for Python3 (coming from Java, I ever wanted it). At the moment I found your answer - now I'm rewriting stuff because this is sooooo great. Since 2011? Awful! There is so many code online which does not take care of type hinting posibility, which shows a programmers intention clearly to others as well as help in own blindfolded moments. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 27):

Actually there is no need as python is a dynamic language, **BUT** if you want to specify a return value then do this

```
def foo(a) -> int: #after arrow type the return type 
       return 1 + a
```

But it won't really help you much. It doesn't raise exceptions in the same way like in staticly-typed language like java, c, c++. Even if you returned a string, it won't raise any exceptions.

and then for argument type do this

```py
def foo(a: int) -> int:
      return a+ 1
```

after the colon (`:`)you can specify the argument type.
This won't help either, to prove this here is an example:

```py
def printer(a: int) -> int: print(a)

printer("hello")
```

The function above actually just returns `None`, because we didn't return anything, but we did tell it we would return `int`, but as I said it doesn't help. Maybe it could help in IDEs (Not all but few like `pycharm` or something, but not on `vscode`)

Answer (score 10):

I attended a coursera course, there was lesson in which, we were taught about design recipe.

Below docstring format I found preety useful.

```
def area(base, height):
    '''(number, number ) -> number    #**TypeContract**
    Return the area of a tring with dimensions base   #**Description**
    and height

    >>>area(10,5)          #**Example **
    25.0
    >>area(2.5,3)
    3.75
    '''
    return (base * height) /2
```

I think if docstrings are written in this way, it might help a lot to developers.

Link to video **[Do watch the video]** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAPg6Vb_LgI

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question >10 years later, there are now 2 things I use to manage this:

- **type hints** (as already mentioned in other answers)
- **dataclasses**, when parameter or return type hints become unwieldy/hard to read

As an example of the latter, say I have a function

```
def do_something(param:int) -> list[tuple[list, int|None]]:
   ...
   return result
```

I would now rewrite using a dataclass, e.g. along the lines of:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Stat:
    entries: list
    value: int | None = None

 def do_something(param:int) -> list[Stat]:
   ...
   return result
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should use docstrings to make your classes and functions more friendly to other programmers:

More: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring

Some editors allow you to see docstrings while typing, so it really makes work easier.

Comment: +1: document it, it's the only sane way, and that's the case for statically typed languages too. Return types are an insignificant fraction of the whole picture.

Comment: I like my types thank you very much. Documentation + types = heaven

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

In Python a function doesn't always have to return a variable of the same type (although your code will be more readable if your functions do always return the same type).  That means that you can't specify a single return type for the function.

In the same way, the parameters don't always have to be the same type too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since it's a dynamically type language ;)

Read this for reference: [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Answer (score 0):

Docstrings (and documentation in general). Python 3 introduces (optional) function annotations, as described in [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) (but don't leave out docstrings)

Answer (score 0):

> For example: how to describe concisely in a docstring that a function returns a list of tuples, with each tuple of the form (node_id, node_name, uptime_minutes) and that the elements are respectively a string, string and integer?

Um... There is no "concise" description of this.  It's complex.  You've designed it to be complex.  And it requires complex documentation in the docstring.

Sorry, but complexity is -- well -- complex.

Comment: OK. Off-topic (sort-of): but what would be a cleaner design then? Classes?

Comment: @Rabarberski: Not necessarily.  Complexity sounds unavoidable here.  Concise is not always achievable or even desirable.

Comment: An obvious way to document this kind of thing is by using something similar to Java generics, as in: list<tuple<int, str, int>>. But that's not the Python way, for better or for worse.