# How to write type hints for a function returning itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

```py
from typing import Callable


def f() -> Callable:
    return f
```

How to explicitly define `f`'s type? like `Callable[[], Callable]`

I think it is slightly like a linked list, but I can't implement it.

```py
from typing import Union


class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next: Union[Node, None] = None
```

Comment: more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336320/how-to-know-function-return-type-and-argument-types

Comment: But this seems to be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67004199/724039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @chepner's answer is great. If you really do want to express this as a recursive Callable type, then you could restructure the function as a callable class and do something like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class F:
    def __call__(self) -> F:
        return self


f = F()
```

You can test this with mypy to see that it maintains its type on future calls:

```
g = f()
h = g(1)  # Too many arguments for "__call__" of "F"
i = h()
j = i(2)  # Too many arguments for "__call__" of "F"
k = j()
```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you could use `typing.Literal` to specify the *exact* function being returned, but that doesn't work for a number of reasons:

1. There's no way to refer to `f` using `typing.Literal`. `typing.Literal['f']` is the string literal `'f'`, not a forward reference to the function about to be defined.
2. `f` doesn't necessarily refer to the function being defined. It's a free variable that could refer to something else entirely by the time the function is actually called.

OK, let's loosen our restriction. Let's try to define a type of function that returns a function of its own type. We can at least write a valid type hint:

```
T = typing.Callable[[],'T']

def f() -> T:
    return f
```

but this is only useful as documentation; `mypy` doesn't yet know how to handle recursively defined types like this.

So let's try

```
T1 = Callable[[], 'T2']
T2 = Callable[[], T1]

def f() -> T2:
    return f
```

Oops, `mypy` doesn't like cyclic definitions, either.

So we're left with your original idea, of using the overlay broad type of functions that take no arguments and returns *some* callable.

```
def f() -> Callable[[], Callable]:
    return f
```

---

The problem with the comparison to `Node` is that there's no type-level recursion involved; `next` simply refers to *some* value of type `Node`.